# Как из базы данных WordPress вывести число коментариев в записи?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно вывести из базы: заголовок, ссылку, количество просмотров и количество коментариев. Сейчас не могу никак вывести количество коментариев в записи и они находятся в другой таблице. Спасайте!!)). Записи не стандартные вордпресовские, а из плагина Asgaros Форум.

```
                $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_forum_topics ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
                $posts_comment = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_forum_posts WHERE parent_id=1 LIMIT 3"); 
                ?>
                <ul>

                <?php foreach ($posts as $posts_i) { ?>

                    <li>
                        <a href="/sample-page/?view=thread&id=<?php echo $posts_i->id ?>"><?php echo $posts_i->name ?></a>
                        <span>Просмотры: <?php echo $posts_i->views ?></span>
                        <span>Коментарии:
                        <?php foreach ($posts_comment as $posts_comment_i) { ?>
                                 <?php echo $posts_comment_i->parent_id ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </span>
                    </li>

            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос исправлен после обсуждения в комментариях, то ответ такой: не знаю ничего о плагине Asgaros Форум. Ниже оставляю ответ для стандартных комментариев к записям WordPress.

В WordPress есть функции на любой случай.

```
$num = get_comments_number( $post_id );
```

А чтобы получить комментарии в виде массива

```
$comments = get_comments( $args );
    foreach( $comments as $comment ){
    // вывод
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что записи находятся на плагине Asgaros Форум.
Стандартным выводом получится вывести их?

Comment: А почему у вас в вопросе об этом ни слова? Не знаю, надо смотреть, как работает плагин

Comment: В описании добавил информацию, исправил)

Answer (score 0):

wp_count_comment( $post_id ); возвращает объект с количество комментариев.

Например:

```
$comments_count = wp_count_comments( $post_id );
echo $comments_count->approved;    // выведет количество одобренных комментариев
```

Comment: Оно выведет число коментариев из плагина, а не из вордпреса?
Нужно вытаскивать из базы я так понимаю, только как сделать правильно?
у меня 3 таблицы в базе wp_forum_topics wp_forum_posts wp_forum_forums. Как мне вытягивать данные из wp_forum_posts чтоб они нормально отображались?

Comment: похоже на то, что комментарии предоставлены в виде записей определенного типа. если так, то можно попробовать ```wp_count_posts( $post_type )```  если способ рабочий, сообщите, я исправлю свой ответ :)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста куда єто нужно вставить в моем коде? А  то я не совсем понимаю

Comment: сделал скринн базы, может както поможет)
http://joxi.net/KAgBexaCgYKbj2
 может как то сумировать посты из одноковым  parent_id и передавать конкретной записи?